# How to increase the speed of this MongoDB query?

Tags: performance, mongodb, mapreduce

MongoDB 2.0.7 & PHP 5

I'm trying to count the length of each array. Every document has one array. I want to get the number of elements in each array and the ID of the document. There are no indexes except from Id.

Here's my code:

```
$map = new MongoCode("function() {
    emit(this._id,{
    '_id':this._id,'cd':this.cd,'msgCount':this.cs[0].msgs.length}
    );
}");

$reduce = new MongoCode("function(k, vals) {
    return vals[0];
}");

$cmmd = smongo::$db->command(array(
    "mapreduce" => "sessions",
    "map" => $map,
    "reduce" => $reduce,
    "out" => "result"));
```

These are the timings. As you can see, the query is very slow

```
Array
(
[result] => result
[timeMillis] => 29452
[counts] => Array
(
[input] => 106026
[emit] => 106026
[reduce] => 0
[output] => 106026
)
[ok] => 1
)
```

How can I reduce the timings?

Comment: use 2.2 and aggregation framework.

Comment: @JonathanOng Please take into consideration that 2.2 is not yet stable. As such you cannot just say "use 2.2 and aggregation framework" for answers until 2.2 is stable, and as well Stennies answer is actually better than the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to frequently need the counts for your arrays, a better approach would be to include a `count` field in your actual documents.  Otherwise you are going to be scanning all documents to do the count (as per your Map/Reduce example).

You can use an [Atomic Operation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-Modifieroperations) such as [`$inc`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc) to increment/decrement this count at the same time as you are updating the arrays.